# Are there any special considerations involved in designing manual flight controls for supersonic/hypersonic aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design, flight-controls, supersonic, hypersonic

What things, if any, might need to be taken into account in the design of manual flight controls for supersonic or hypersonic aircraft that *wouldn’t* need to be taken into account with manual controls for subsonic aircraft?

Answer (score 1):

In the transonic region, control forces [may become too high for manual control](https://www.quora.com/What-is-it-like-approaching-the-sound-barrier-in-an-aircraft-designed-for-subsonic-flight) (e.g. controls froze in WW2 planes diving at high speeds), so supersonic aircraft usually have powered controls rather than manual, cable-operated controls.

You also get [CoG shift](http://www.aerospaceweb.org/question/planes/q0199.shtml) you have to compensate for. This is often done via a Mach trim system or by automatic fuel transfer.